# Did the 12 disciples represent all 12 tribes?

Tags: disciple

I know that Jesus chose 12 disciples (apostles) to represent the 12 tribes. My question do we know if each of the 12 were from a different tribe of Israel?  In other words are all of the tribes represented in the 12 apostles?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 10):

From the simple fact that there were at least two sets of brothers, we can say for sure that their **primary** tribal identities were not from all 12 tribes.

If you included all their tribal ancestors from their mothers' sides as well, then we'd expect that all the tribes were represented just from the fact that people moved and married around a lot, but there's no actual evidence for it either way.

Comment: Why so few votes up? This is strictly speaking the right answer.

Comment: @curiousdanii You sholud also mention that 10 tribes got "lost" over the years. So there were only the tribes Juda, Benjamin and Levi at the time of Jesus.

Comment: @K-HB I don't know that that is actually true.

Comment: @curiousdannii see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Lost_Tribes) and 2 Kings 17:6; historic-critical many things are unclear

Comment: @K-HB, the tribes weren't lost to history yet:   _The Jewish historian Josephus (37–100 CE) wrote that "the ten tribes are beyond the Euphrates till now, and are an immense multitude and not to be estimated in numbers"._ -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Lost_Tribes)

Comment: It is indeed likely that all of the twelve tribes has at least one person who is an ancestor of one of the twelve apostles. But frankly that's probably true of any random selection of twelve people.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words are all of the tribes represented in the 12 apostles?

Not in this age. But in the new age, yes.

> Jesus said to them, “Truly, I say to you, in the new world, when
> the Son of Man will sit on his glorious throne, you who have followed
> me will also sit on twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of
> Israel. ([Matthew 19:28 ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2019%3A28&version=ESV))
>
> and I assign to you, as my Father assigned to me, a kingdom, that
> you may eat and drink at my table in my kingdom and sit on thrones
> judging the twelve tribes of Israel. ([Luke 22:29-30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=%20Luke%2022%3A29-30&version=ESV))

Comment: Just because 12 people judge the 12 tribes doesn't mean they represent the 12 tribes.